# Is the (new) reviewing system broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-page

I think the reviewing system is broken since the last maintanance.

New questions are comming in but are not shown in the review system.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Is this fixed now?

Comment: @werner: Seems to bi fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: @werner: Seems to be broken again. Rewiev page does not completely load here. Latest first post was not shown in review page ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the review queue for [First Posts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts) is broken. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78518/510) non-answer (now deleted and only visible for 10k-users) showed up in the queue for "Low Quality Posts", but not for "First Posts".